# Android: how to avoid the pressed visual of a button in a listview item when pressing the list item

Tags: android, listview, button, listitem

I have a listview, where there is a button in each list item. When I press the list item, I found the button inside also showed the visual effort of clicking. How can I prevent this visual effort of clicking the button when pressing the list item?

Here is the layout of the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="#DFDEDF" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/LocationImageView"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:src="@drawable/icn_location_yellow_30x30"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LocationTitleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/LocationDetailButton"
    android:layout_width="21dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_btn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but I can't figure out how to fix it using the accepted answer. Can you provide more details how you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `onItemClickListener(...)` of `listview`,you can temporarily disable button's click.But don't forget to re-enable it when other item is selected. I haven't tried this but it might work.